$f(x) = C_1 * x_1 + C_2 * x_2 + \ldots \text{(max/min this function)}$, how to solve it with simplex method?
The statement is something like:
$f(x) = C_1 * x_1 + C_2 * x_2 + \ldots \text{(max/min this function)}$
Constraints:
$c_{11}*x_1 + c_{12}*x_2 + ... = value_1$
$c_{21}*x_1 + c_{22}*x_2 + ... = value_2$
...
How to solve this? I don't understand my notes much, and the fact that everything on the internet that solves this problem WITH inequalities ($\le$ value) and slack variables makes me confused.
In my notes, there is a simplex table constructed:
Columns represent base variables, rows non-base variables. Not every variable + slack variable represents a row.
For example, I will represent the data of a problem with 4 variables:
$\min f(x) = -4x_1 - 2x_2 - x_3 - 5x_2$
$0 * x_1 + 2 * x_2 + 1 * x_3 + 4 * x_2 = 10$
$1 * x_1 + 3 * x_2 + 0 * x_3 + 1 * x_4 = 9$
$x1,x2,x3,x4 \ge 0$
Now in my notes, a table is constructed, with the columns being $x_3, x_1$ and rows $x_2, x_4$, and an extra row and column that I don't know what they mean.
For the 4 cells I will note the values from my notes:
$(x_2,x_3) = 2, (x_2, x_1) = 3$
$(x_4,x_3) = 4, (x_4, x_1) = 1$
These look like the constants used in the constraint part. There is also an extra row and column like I said, so the table is actually a $3\times 3$ one, but I don't understand what those values represent.

Please use MathJax (put your equations inside dollar-signs and use LaTeX format) in order to make your question more readable.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

You don't need Linear Programming in this case. Simply use the Lagrange multipliers method.

Here's a simplified version of the model where $z$ represents the objective function value:
$$\min z= -4x_1 - 7x_2 - x_3$$
$$0x_1 + 6x_2 + 1x_3 = 10$$
$$1x_1 + 3x_2 + 0x_3 + 1x_4 = 9$$
The Simplex Method takes advantage of the standard form representation of a linear model to find basic feasible solutions and for the algorithm to have a starting point. Then, we can create a simple tableau (the tableau method appears in many forms) like so:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & RHS\newline\hline
z & 1 & 4 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 0\newline\hline
? & 0 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 10\newline\hline
x_4 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 9\newline\hline
\end{array}$$
Notice the "$?$" in the basic variable column, for a basic variable to exist in a row we need a column in reduced echelon form with the one located in that row. We can achieve this by subtracting the second row from the first row to get the following:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & RHS\newline\hline
z & 1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -10\newline\hline
x_3 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 10\newline\hline
x_4 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 9\newline\hline
\end{array}$$
Now, the Simplex Method for a minimization problem operates by taking the largest reduced cost value in the objective row (excluding the $z$ variable, and in our case we will select the $x_1$ column) and selecting that column to perform the ratio test where we divide the column values (CV), excluding the objective row, against the right-hand-side (RHS) values like so: $\frac{RHS}{CV}$. Note, in the event where $CV\le0$, we say the result is $\infty$ and do not pivot that row. For our tableau, we have the following ratio test:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & RHS & \text{Ratio Test}\newline\hline
z & 1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -10 & -\newline\hline
x_3 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 10 & \frac{10}{0}=\infty\newline\hline
x_4 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 9 & \frac{9}{1}=9\newline\hline
\end{array}$$
Therefore the $x_4$ variable will leave the solution and the $x_1$ variable will enter. As mentioned before, every basic variable will need to have a corresponding column in reduced echelon form. Thus, we will need to do elementary row operations to achieve this for the selected column like so:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & RHS\newline\hline
z & 1 & 0 & -11 & 0 & -4 & -46\newline\hline
x_3 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 10\newline\hline
x_1 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 9\newline\hline
\end{array}$$
Since there are no more strictly positive values in the objective function row, we are done with the minimization problem. Therefore the optimal solution is $x_1 = 9$ and $x_3 = 10$ with $z=-46$.

In this case, it was easy to find an initial solution. Generally, this is not always the case. There exist techniques that use artificial variables for = and $\ge$ constraints called the Big-M or Two-Phase methods. This allows for the Simplex Method to have an initial solution to improve upon. For the following model,
$$\min z= -4x_1 - 7x_2 - x_3$$
$$0x_1 + 6x_2 + 1x_3 = 10$$
$$1x_1 + 3x_2 + 0x_3 + 1x_4 = 9$$
we can treat $x_4$ as a slack variable for the second constraint, and add an artificial variable to the first constraint to set-up the model for the Big-M method:
$$\min z= -4x_1 - 7x_2 - x_3 + Ma_1$$
$$0x_1 + 6x_2 + 1x_3 +a_1 = 10$$
$$1x_1 + 3x_2 + 0x_3 + 1x_4 = 9$$
In the tableau, this will look like the following:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & a_1 & x_4 & RHS\newline\hline
z & 1 & 4 & 7 & 1 & -M& 0 & 0\newline\hline
? & 0 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 1& 0 & 10\newline\hline
x_4 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 0& 1 & 9\newline\hline
\end{array}$$
Picking the $a_1$ column for reduced echelon form we get the following:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & a_1 & x_4 & RHS\newline\hline
z   & 1 & 4 & 6M+7 & M+1 & 0& 0 & 10M\newline\hline
a_1 & 0 & 0 & 6   & 1 &  1& 0 & 10\newline\hline
x_4 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 0& 1 & 9\newline\hline
\end{array}$$
and we would proceed as we did for the above example. This is how we usually treat equality constraints in the Simplex Method.
